# How is discord api detecting your ip?

Tags: api, discord

How is the discord API detecting your IP when rate-limiting your computer?

Even by doing requests trough tor and resetting the connection every 5 requests to change my IP, it still rates limit me (you probably know what I am doing, just note that it's for fun, quarantine is boring)

How does it know it still your computer? How does it work?

Comment: With a little magic.

Answer (score 2):

Exposing an IP is a fundamental part of how the internet works. When you connect to a service, you are sending data to its IP address, including your IP address so that the service may reply to you. There's no way around this, as if the IP given was incorrect, you would not get a reply from that service. Changing your IP using a proxy, VPN, or like you've been using, TOR, is still exposing the IP address of the end point of the proxy, so that the service can respond to the proxy and have the proxy send the request back to you.

Typically, if you are hitting rate-limits that often, you are doing something which is not permitted by the service you are using. If you continually hit rate-limits, the service will catch on and apply harsher rate limits, or even terminate your account. In discord especially, hitting rate-limits that often would indicate you are performing requests with malicious intent. If that's not true, you should re-evaluate how you're going about what you're doing, as there will be a better solution to your problem.

Comment: There is a way around this, through NAT, a proxy or Tor.

Comment: No, that is not a solution, You are still exposing the NAT/proxy/TOR exit IP address.

Comment: Yes, but not your own IP, which you claim. OP also states that the limit is still applied after changing Tor exit nodes, i.e. using a different "client IP" that the service sees. I agree with the rest of your answer, but not that part.

Comment: They have stated that he needs to change IP's *every 5 requests*, which indicates they are not getting the 429 response on the first 5 requests on a new IP. While, I'm unsure personally if discord applies rate-limits across IP's based on other identifying tokens, I have been told in the past that they do not.

Comment: The point is that Discord is blocking a particular repeated action of OP, even if they start doing it again from a different IP. Their question then is _"How do they detect my IP"_, and the answer is _"They don't, they use other identifiers, heuristics and whatnot"_, and not _"Your client IP is sent with every request"_, because it isn't, they're using Tor.

Comment: Yes, I can see how my wording is ambiguous between 'your personal IP' and 'an IP address in general', let me reword my answer. But as well,  they are stating that its not instantly that they get rate-limited, which is implying that they're actually just hitting the rate-limit for whatever endpoint they are using that quickly, unless that was another ambiguity with their original question.